# Changed A Record to point to new server. Non www 404

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I've moved my site to be hosted with Digital Ocean. I've set the A records to point to the severs IP address. The www lands on the site as expected but the non www 404s.

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at mydomainhere.com Port 80
```

Apache config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName mydomainhere.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/laravel>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: Use ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com

Comment: Add an `@` record to your ip address. More info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Or write htaccess redirect non www to www

Comment: No luck with either.

Comment: It can take some time for dns to change to a new domain, maybe all you have to do now is wait.

Comment: Aha yes, I'm not sure which worked but it is now. Thank you!